# AES Fault Attack

Tags: aes, side-channel-attack, fault-attack

Induce random fault (non-zero) error in one
byte before MixColumns in Round 9

I get last round key with 32 bit (4 bytes) missing
(Missing are bytes 1, 8, 11, 14)

How can I recover these key bytes without the need of computing 2^32 keys

Comment: Why are you afraid of letting your computer do some work? 4 billion isn't *that* much...

Comment: any reference to the paper or technique you are implementing?